# Fineuploader addFiles ie 8/9

Tags: fine-uploader

I have been building an audio recorder which falls back to flash for browsers which do not support the getUserMedia api (which is then passed to the page via an external interface).

I am wondering if it is possible to upload arbitrary Blobs/Files in ie 8/9 while using the `iframeSupport` config using finuploader.

Currently I am using a polyfill for the Blob api when it is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible, as the File API is not available in IE9 and older.  No polyfill will allow you to turn a file input element into a `File` or `Blob` object unless the browser supports the File API.

You can, however, pass `<input type="file">` elements into Fine Uploader's `addFiles` API method.